# Clearfix with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, clearfix

I have an issue with twitter bootstrap that looks a little bit strange to me. I have a sidebar with fixed with at the left side and a main area.

```
<div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>Z</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <a>RIGHT</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>MOVED BELOW Z</div>
</div>
```

```css
#sidebar {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

#main {
  background: green;
  margin-left: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Inside the main area I have some content with pull-left and pull-right with is cleared by a clearfix.

The problem is that the content below the clearfix-div is moved to be lower than the sidebar-content.

I made a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZguC7/

I solved the problem by setting the "overflow: collapse" to #main, but I dont understand it and would be very happy if somebody can explain what is causing this issue.

Comment: I updated your fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ZguC7/123/. I just changed the position of closing tag of 'clearfix' div and it corrected the height

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I wanted. The "Hello" text should not be in same line with "FOO"

Answer (score 39):

`clearfix` should contain the floating elements but in your html you have added `clearfix` only after floating right that is your `pull-right` so you should do like this:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>Z</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <a>RIGHT</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>MOVED BELOW Z</div>
</div>
```

[see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/ZguC7/5/)

---

Happy to know you solved the problem by setting overflow properties. However this is also good idea to clear the float. Where you have floated your elements you could add `overflow: hidden;` as you have done in your main.

Comment: I also just add a `<div class='clearfix'></div>` where my 'line break' should be, and it works nicely.