# div background color not setting all area

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing 3 div inside it. My problem is when am setting background color to first div, the div inside first div is not applying the background.

My code is,

```
<div class="how_next">
    <div class="how_next_single" align="center">
        <p><img src="images/livemonitoring.png" /></p>
        <p>Heading</p>
        <h3>Description</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="how_next_single" align="center">
        <p><img src="images/livemonitoring.png" /></p>
        <p>Heading</p>
        <h3>Description</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="how_next_last" align="center">
        <p><img src="images/livemonitoring.png" /></p>
        <p>Heading</p>
        <h3>Description</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

My style is,

```
.how_next {
    height:auto;
    background-color:#E9E9E9;
    padding:15px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.how_next_single {
    width:32%;
    float:left;
}
.how_next_last {
    width:32%;
    float:right;
}
```

Now the output is

[image: Output]

What is the problem in my coding. Is there any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use floating elements inside a wrapper you need to clear them. There are various ways to clear them using clearfix technique, using overflow:hidden, etc.

So, you need to do just:

```
.how_next {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

You may have an interest in these q/a:

[what is clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

[which method of clearfix is best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

[clearfix with twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630587/clearfix-with-twitter-bootstrap/18631608#18631608)

[all about floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: Note with this solution that at some point, if any contained element want's to exceed the bounds of the parent, it won't be able to - e.g. a dropdown

Answer (score 0):

See this is the perfect answer of your query.

Css:

```
.how_next {
  height:auto;
  background-color:#E9E9E9;
  padding:15px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
 margin-top:10px;
}
 .how_next_single {
   width:32%;
  float:left
 }
```

Working [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/w7rxj818/)

Answer (score 0):

What about create a new class style:

```
.clearfix{
   clear:both;
}
```

Then add it to the end of your HTML:

```
<div class="how_next">
   <div class="how_next_single" align="center">
       <p><img src="images/livemonitoring.png" /></p>
       <p>Heading</p>
       <h3>Description</h3>
   </div>

   <div class="how_next_single" align="center">
       <p><img src="images/livemonitoring.png" /></p>
       <p>Heading</p>
       <h3>Description</h3>
   </div>

   <div class="how_next_last" align="center">
       <p><img src="images/livemonitoring.png" /></p>
       <p>Heading</p>
      <h3>Description</h3>
   </div>

   <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

And don't use such a things like **align="center"** it's not a proper way of centering things due to HTML5 standards. All those things should be achieved by CSS, you shouln't write any styles in your HTML tags, that's a good practice.

Hmmm, I also think that you don't need **height:auto** in your **how_next** style.

### Why clear:both?

You must do this in your case, because you're using floating elements, which won't make your parent expand by them.

Have a look!
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
 <div class="clear"></div>
```

and give him style:

```
<style>
   .clear{both;with:100%;}
</style>
```

after the .how_next_last div

Example:

```
<div class="how_next">
    <div class="how_next_single" align="center">
        <p><img src="images/livemonitoring.png" /></p>
        <p>Heading</p>
        <h3>Description</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="how_next_single" align="center">
        <p><img src="images/livemonitoring.png" /></p>
        <p>Heading</p>
        <h3>Description</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="how_next_last" align="center">
        <p><img src="images/livemonitoring.png" /></p>
        <p>Heading</p>
        <h3>Description</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your perfect answer for css.

```
.how_next {
    height:auto;
    background-color:#E9E9E9;
    padding:15px;
    font-size :16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
   }
.how_next_single {
    width:32%;
    float:left;
  }
.how_next_last {
    width:32%;
    float:right;
   }
```